# Android urlConnection setUseCache(false) doesnt work

Tags: android, url, caching, connection

I m using this code at the moment. It works perfectly when device doesnt have internet(It doesnt use cache) but when I update the txt file, it doesnt update it in app, it uses the previous one.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.myhost.com/ygs/somefile.txt");
                    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Add a random number or a timestring to the querystring
`URL url = new URL("http://www.myhost.com/ygs/somefile.txt?r="+Math.random());`

Comment: thanx @Hasanaga it works ^^

Comment: I add as answer. If my answer helped you, pleaseconsider upvoting it and accepting it. Thanks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a random number or a timestring to the querystring URL

`url = new URL("http://www.myhost.com/ygs/somefile.txt?r="+Math.random());`

Comment: Thanx ! that s clever